# PhantomJS webdriver - Python - Mobile User Agent does not load images on some sites

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm using Python with PhantomJS to grab a screenshot of a website, which seems to work with this user agent:

```
user_agent = ("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36")
```

However, I want the page in a mobile format, so I've tried using:

```
user_agent = ("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12A4345d Safari/600.1.4")
```

and

```
user_agent = ("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A4449d Safari/9537.53")
```

...those work for most sites, but some sites do not load images.  For example, http://www.cnn.com and http://www.washingtonpost.com load images, but https://www.wsj.com often does not and http://www.foxnews.com never loads images using the mobile user agents.

Any idea what changes I can make to always load images?  I've tried waiting for the page to load.  Here is more of the code:

```
# set user agent
user_agent = ("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12A4345d Safari/600.1.4")
# user_agent = ("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A4449d Safari/9537.53")
# user_agent = ("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36")

dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = user_agent
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.javascriptEnabled"] = True
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.loadImages"] = True
# dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.viewportSize"] = {
#   "width" : 640
#   , "height" : 640
# }

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_log_path=os.path.devnull, executable_path="/var/task/phantomjs", service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true'], desired_capabilities=dcap)
browser.set_window_size(640,640)
browser.implicitly_wait(5) #seconds
browser.get(['url'])

# Capture the screenshot
screenshot = browser.get_screenshot_as_png()

# Close the browser
browser.close()
```